# Responsive design working on desktop browser, on mobile-simulator (both Safari and Mozilla Firefox), but not on a real smartphone (Android, iOS)

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, mobile-browser

I tried several lines of code, but I just can't figure out where I went wrong since it's working on a desktop and it SHOULD work on mobile devices as well...

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-      scale=1,    user-scalable=no"</>
```

and in css:

```
@media (max-device-width: 640px) {}
```

http://codepen.io/ctrprt253/pen/QNaVdP

Thx in advance.

Comment: Your `<meta>` tag ends with `</>`, which is not valid. You don't need to close `<meta>` tags; just end it with `>`.

Comment: Did that, still not working, but thx :/

Answer (score 0):

change your code to

```css
@media (max-width:640px){ ... }
```

It will be solved your problem